# Apache 2.4.6 Https Page slowness issue

Tags: java, apache, performance, tomcat, webserver

I configured Apache 2.4 server, which used as a proxy server to my tomcat. There are two(maybe more) applications deployed on my Tomcat & both are accessible only using apache web server IP and port(443-https).

But whenever I tried to access Login.htm page, it took almost 10-15 sec to load a single page. When I tried to log in using username & password, here welcome page took 1 min 20 sec to load.

However, in my local environment (local IP and port(8080-http)) it took 1 sec for login page & 3-4 sec for welcome page. Note - there is no apache web server configured on my local environment.

I tried a lot of performance tuning methods on my apache web server, but none of them working for me. I am not sure what is missing here. Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Below is my apache server configuration.

```
Listen 443 https

SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog

SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 512
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost <APP_SERVER_IP_ADDR>:443>

ServerName <APP_SERVER_IP_ADDR>
ServerAlias <APP_SERVER_IP_ADDR>

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log
TransferLog /var/log/httpd/ssl_access_log
LogLevel info

SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key

<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

    ProxyRequests     Off
    SSLProxyEngine  On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RewriteEngine On
    HostnameLookups off

    <Proxy <APP_SERVER_IP_ADDR>:443>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass         /application1 http://<WEB_SERVER_IP_ADDR>:9660/application1
    ProxyPassReverse  /application1 http://<WEB_SERVER_IP_ADDR>:9660/application1

    ProxyPass         /application2 http://<WEB_SERVER_IP_ADDR>:9660/application2
    ProxyPassReverse  /application2 http://<WEB_SERVER_IP_ADDR>:9660/application2

    <Location /proxy/>
      ProxyPassReverse /
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all     
    </Location> 

    Header edit Location ^http://<APP_SERVER_IP_ADDR>/ https://<APP_SERVER_IP_ADDR>/

    Timeout 10
    ProxyTimeout 10
    ProxyBadHeader Ignore

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging a lot into apache API, I finally found that there is a big problem in my application.

We are trying to implement the 3-Tier architecture in our production system. As we are using apache web server (as a proxy server) from Web-Server to App Server, there are lot of Js, CSS and images files transferred from my application.

When user requesting Login.htm (or accessing any other page) from WebServer, this request will be responded by my app server. As there are lot of Js, CSS and images files are transferred from App to Web, and finally Web to browser, the signle request consumes around 15 seconds.

To overcome this situation, I moved all Js, CSS and images related files to web server. So all HTML related stuff now loading from Web server and not from app server. For this, I just added below lines in my ssl.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ProxyPass /application1/resources !
```

The path present in DocumentRoot is context path of my Web server, where I created  'application1' directory and added 'resources' directory where all js, css and image files are present.

Now my application take 4-7 seconds to load Login.htm page.